# Send event when cassandra delete a document with TTL

Tags: java, elasticsearch, cassandra, nosql, change-data-capture

I'm using elasticsearch with cassandra to store my data, ES for search and cassandra as a principal database. 
In order to delete old documents I'm using insertion with TTL which ensure the deletion of the document after a specific amount of time. 
Cassandra do well the job, but for me it's only the half job done because I have to delete the same doucument on ES to ensure synchronisation between ES and C*.

I would like to know if there are some sort of events that cassandra send when it deletes a document based on its TTL value. In that case I force a delete directely in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Im not aware of such events but you could try elassandra - its a fork of cassandra and is tightly coupled with elasticsearch and deleted rows from elassandra will be removed from elastic as well.

https://www.elassandra.io/

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch also supports TTL, you can use same TTL in both Cassandra & ES  document. though can't guarantee consistency as both are independent of each other. If you need consistency ellasandra might be worth looking for.